# Python insert oracle data into sql server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, oracle, python-2.7

> I'm currently looking for a python script that will extract data from oracle database and insert it into an SQL SERVER Database

> Currently I have created a python script to extract data from oracle database, below is my code

```
import csv
import cx_Oracle

# establish connection
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(
user="username", 
password="password",
dsn="servername/PROD")

# create cursor object
cursor = connection.cursor()

# query to display all the data 
cursor.execute("""SELECT *
FROM LOTTO_BI.LOTO_DRAW_RESULTS 
ORDER BY DRAW_NUM""")

# print each row in the cursor
for i in cursor:
print(i)
```

> What is missing in my code is the part to insert the oracle data into a SQL SERVER table

Answer (score 1):

Notes for users who reach here in/after 2023:

1. For the sake of simplicity of code, I have added `pandas` to the import which allows for easier data extract and load.
2. `cx_Oracle` is now `oracledb`.
3. To make things further simpler, adding `SQLAlchemy` to replace `pyodbc` and `cx_Oracle` as it can handle both the database connections.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import csv


# establish source engine
ora = create_engine("oracle+oracledb://username:password@servername:port/PROD", pool_recycle=600,)

# create connection
ora_conn = ora.connect()

# query all the data as a pandas dataframe
sql = """SELECT *
FROM LOTTO_BI.LOTO_DRAW_RESULTS 
ORDER BY DRAW_NUM""")
data = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)

# close source connection
ora_conn.close()

# Establish destination engine to the SQL Server database
mssql = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:password@sql_server_host:port/sql_server_db?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server", pool_recycle=600,)

# create connection
sql_conn = mssql.connect()

# Insert the dataframe into the SQL Server database
# to_sql takes the SQLAlchemy engine instead of connection object.
data.to_sql(sql_server_table, con=mssql,
                    index=False,
                    if_exists="append",)

# Commit changes
sql_conn.commit()

# Close connections
sql_conn.close()
```

This assumes that the table in Oracle and the table in SQL Server have the same structure, with the same number of columns and data types.

Additional arguments and options about SQLAlchemy and Pandas can be found at the following official documentation pages.

Connecting to Oracle DB from SQLAlchemy - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/oracle.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.oracledb

Connecting to MS SQL Server from SQLAlchemy - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc

Pandas DataFrame APIs -

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

These are the simplest forms of extract and load.
Performance, error handling and other attributes need to be added additionally to the script.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyodbc
import csv
import cx_Oracle

# establish connection
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(
user="username", 
password="password",
dsn="servername/PROD")

# create cursor object
cursor = connection.cursor()

# query to display all the data 
cursor.execute("""SELECT *
FROM LOTTO_BI.LOTO_DRAW_RESULTS 
ORDER BY DRAW_NUM""")

# Fetch all rows
oracle_rows = cursor.fetchall()


# Establish a connection to the SQL Server database
sql_server_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=sql_server_host;DATABASE=sql_server_db;UID=user;PWD=password')

# create cursor object
sql_server_cursor = sql_server_conn.cursor()

# Insert the rows into the SQL Server database
for row in oracle_rows:
    sql_server_cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sql_server_table VALUES (?, ?, ?)', row)

# Commit changes
sql_server_conn.commit()


# Close connections
oracle_cursor.close()
oracle_conn.close()
sql_server_cursor.close()
sql_server_conn.close()
```

I have the added the code below to your code. This assumes that the table in Oracle and the table in SQL Server have the same structure, with the same number of columns and data types.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, to make things simple, just use `pandas` library which can translate from one sql engine to another with its `to_sql()` method.

**As I don't have Oracle database locally, this example shows you how to do the same thing and insert MYSQL data to SQLite database**

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import mysql.connector

# Connect to the MYSQL Database using the mysql.connector library
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='password',
    database='storefront2')

# Create a SQLAlchemy engine for the SQLite database
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///storefront2.db')

# Read `store_product` data from the MYSQL database
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM store_product', connection)

# Write the data from the DataFrame to the SQLite database
df.to_sql('store_product', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

As for you, `connection` would be a connection to your `Oracle` database (you can keep your connection) and `engine` would be connection to `SQLServer`.

Edit: to create engine for SQLServer, use:

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname")
```

Or checkout `SQLAlchemy documentation`:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server